# Request in MySQL in two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, inner-join

MySQL. I'm working with database and i have 2 tables. 1st table is mane, it has id and NAME. 2nd connected with 1st via FOREIGN KEY and has COST. How to get such request that has NAME of 1st and sum of COST of 2nd tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just `join`, `group by` and `sum()`. Assuming that the foreign key column in `table2` is `t1_id`:

```
select t1.name, sum(t2.cost) total_cost
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t2.t1_id = t1.id
group by t1.id, t1.name
```

If you want to allow names that have no match in `table2`, then use `left join` instead, and maybe `coalesce(sum(t2.cost), 0)` as well.

Comment: Yes,  want to allow names that have no match in table2

Comment: @glu: so use the `left join` solution.